# Python error in Update Cursor for ArcGIS: " 'int' object has no attribute 'type' "

Tags: arcpy, cursor, null

I am fairly new to python and am trying to make a script that looks through an ArcGIS feature class and updates `<null>` values to `'tbd'` or `99999` based on the field type (string, double/integer).  Right around the `if rowU[field] == None and row[field.type] == "String":` line of code, I receive an error saying `'int' object has no attribute 'type'`.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I have the `elif` statement commented out now, I'll remove the `###` when I update the first `if` statement successfully.

```
import arcpy
try:
 path = r'*path to my data*'
 fieldObs = arcpy.ListFields(path)
 fieldNames = []
 for field in fieldObs:
     fieldNames.append(field.name)
 del fieldObs
 fieldCount = len(fieldNames)


 with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(path, fieldNames) as curU:
     for row in curU:
         rowU = row
         for field in range(fieldCount):
             ### statement for strings
             if rowU[field] == None and row[field.type] == "String":
                 rowU[field] = "tbd"
             ### statement for doubles or integers
             ###elif rowU[field] == None:
                 ###rowU[field] = "99999"
         curU.updateRow(rowU)

 del curU

except Exception as e:
    print("Error: " + e.args[0])
```

Comment: I suggest removing try/except statements when testing and presenting most Python code here because they can mask otherwise useful error messages.

Answer (score 5):

```
row[field.type]
```

`field` is just a simple integer counter and has no type property.

```
if rowU[field] == None and type(row[field]) == "String":
```

You need the built-in `type()` function so try the above instead.

Comment: Update, the script now runs fine, but nothing updates in the GIS (?). I think there is some disconnect and the script isn't recognizing "String" as a legit type.  If I add a print statement to list all the types in the database, I get a list like this: ```<class 'int'>
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'str'>```. I tried changing to "str", 'str', and str, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: You might want to debug/print `rowU[field]` and `type(row[field])` to make sure the contents are what you are expecting.

Comment: String is not a python type, `str` is.

Answer (score 5):

Convert

```
if rowU[field] == None and row[field.type] == "String"
```

into

```
if rowU[field] == None and type(row[field]) == str
```

Comment: Thank you as well!! Got it going great now.